# navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, sicklms, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I was wondering if anyone had a working version of a launch file for a
navigation stack, using a SICK LMS rangefinder for the sensor and their
odometer and transform nodes, that they could let me look at to get a
better understanding of how the navigation stack fits together. I've been
doing the tutorial RobotSetup for the navigation stack, and after
completing the transform configuration portion and using

node pkg="sicktoolbox_wrapper" type="sicklms" name="sicklms" output="screen"

with its corresponding parameters for the sick lms rangefinder I seem to be hung up. I don't quite understand where to put the odometry code, nor how to reference the transform configurations or odometry  file for the node requirements during the launch file.
Also, I'm using a Pioneer AT3 so I didn't know if there was an odometry package for this robot or not? Or if it is possible to use ROSARIA or p2os to build a map of a building with the robot?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Jason

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9587/navigation-stack/) by [Jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/359/jason/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer in two parts:

1. **Sample Navigation Using SICK**
   Take a look at [cwru-ros-pkg](https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/tree/master/cwru_semi_stable) for a complete navigation stack setup using the SICK laser. The launch files you should look at are the `cwru_bringup_no_tele.launch` and `cwru_nav/start_nav.launch` (though `start_nav.launch` assumes that someone has already brought up a `map_server`, like in `cwru_nav/start_amcl_2ndfloor.launch`). You should be able to trace the included launch files, configs and such to get an example working navigation stack for our differential drive robots.
2. **Odometry for the Pioneer**
   Yes, you can use something like [p2os](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os) to get odometry from a Pioneer. See the [Getting Started with p2os](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20p2os) tutorial for how to setup your Pioneer. As long as p2os outputs reasonable odometry estimates and the required transforms, you should be able to use your SICK to make a map with [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/359/jason/) on 2011-04-26**:
Sorry it's been awhile since I asked this I've been stuck doing other work. If you were running the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup  and you were to run the line roscreate-pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep to create your package, what would your dependencies be for your setup? I created the transform function and it seems to work fine, but I'm unsure as to where to put the sample Odometry code and how to reference the transform code. I'm trying to do roscreate-pkg robot_2dnav move_base robot_setup_tf sicktoolbox_wrapper and then I'm unsure what to put for the odometer dependency. Also the robot_setup_tf doesnt take so is this not how to reference the tf I created earlier in that same tutorial? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks